# How do "cpushares" in ResourceGovernancePolicy works?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Deployed 2 versions of the same container app to Service Fabric with different "cpuShares" setting (500 and 1500). I expected when both hosted on the the same host that version 1 will be allocated a third of CPU then second one but in reality both of them eating 50% CPU.
[image]

[image]
[image]

App Manifest

```
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="PI_CalculatorType" ApplicationTypeVersion="770Shares" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="PI_Web_Service_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="PI_Web_ServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="770Shares" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <Policies>
      <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">
        <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="PI_Web_ServiceTypeEndpoint" />
      </ContainerHostPolicies>
      <ResourceGovernancePolicy CodePackageRef="Code" MemorySwapInMB="4084" MemoryReservationInMB="1024" CpuShares="770" />
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="PI_Web_Service">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="PI_Web_ServiceType" InstanceCount="[PI_Web_Service_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

Service manifest

```
<ServiceManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="PI_Web_ServicePkg" Version="770Shares" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="PI_Web_ServiceType" UseImplicitHost="true" />
  </ServiceTypes>
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="770Shares">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ContainerHost>
        <ImageName>artisticcheese/iis:latest</ImageName>
      </ContainerHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="770Shares" />
  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="PI_Web_ServiceTypeEndpoint" Protocol="http" UriScheme="http" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

URL to call to reproduce

```
http://192.168.1.193:20001/pi/service.svc/pi/40000
```

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? I seem to run into the same issue with memory parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with preview bits for container support. It is fixed for upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

[CpuShares](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/cpu-share-constraint) is relative to a set of [1024](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#/cpu) shares of CPU by default.

> Set this flag to a value greater or less than the default of 1024 to
>   increase or reduce the container’s weight, and give it access to a
>   greater or lesser proportion of the host machine’s CPU cycles.

Your 500 setting results in about half the CPU to be used by one service, leaving the rest for the other.

Changing the 500 into 341 should do the trick.

Comment: Did not work. I on purpouse put extreme number of the same application. One is 770 and another one 220. I expected to see 3x time in difference CPU cycles being assigned but in reality it was still 50/50. I'm running process containers on Windows 2016 based off artisticcheese/iis:latest image

Comment: x2 CPU. It's virtual machine. Does this work for you or you are talking from theoretical point of view?

Comment: I've seemed to run into the same issue with memory limits.. when I inspect the docker containers it doesn't even look like the configuration was set properly

Comment: Yes. Hostconfig for containers does not reflect those values at all. I assume it's a bug since the rest of the stuff is in proper location (like port mapping etc) "CpuQuota":0

Comment: It works fine in my environment, provided there's enough CPU pressure. 

If I run an additional process that hogs the CPU, I see my w3wp process maxing out at the configured rate.

Comment: @LoekD Was Cputshares reflected when used docker inspect? It does not reflect in mine

Comment: @GSA - I have run into the same issue. It doesn't look like the ResourceGovernancePolicy element passes on the settings to docker. When I inspect the container everything is still set to 0

Comment: Well @LoekD somehow managed it to work so wondering what is different between our environments. I run SF inside virtual machine on top of Windows 10, isolation is "process"

Comment: @GSA - I'm running it in Windows Server 2016

Comment: @Ryan Please upvote this bug here https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/149

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I saw it working. Turns out it doesn't.

Comment: yes, it's confirmed bug now per github https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/149